# Android WebView losing Cookies in redirects

Tags: android, cookies, webview

My problem is with `WebView` dealing with redirects and custom cookies.

I do following:

1. Create instances of `CookieSyncManager` and `CookieManager` in application create
2. Call `sCookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);` in static section in util class
3. Call `sCookieManager.setCookie(url, value);
       sCookieSyncManager.sync();`
4. And finally `mWebView.loadUrl`

What's happening in server side is that it first gets the correct cookie I have set, runs some redirect and cookie seems to be lost. Any ideas, what I am doing wrong here?

I've tried running `setCookie` - `sync` in another thread giving some delay and then `loadUrl` but it didn't help.

All similar posts seem to have solutions which are not working.

Thanks.

UPDATE:

I noticed that using `setCookie` to give multiple Cookies like for example:

```
setCookie("MyCookie=value; Domain=mydomain.com; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; MySecondCookie=value2....)"
```

Only the first one is applied, and then it's gone when server runs redirects on it's own domain.
 **This issue can be fixed settings custom cookies one in a time in a loop.**

I have temporarily added `handler.proceed();` in `onReceivedSslError` and I can see from the logs that it's triggering just before web site redirects and Cookie is lost in on next pages `onPageFinished`, could there be some connection between secure cookies and invalid certificate chains?

Comment: I am facing same issue ? Did you get any solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

Try using not

```
sCookieManager.setCookie(url, value)
```

but

```
sCookieManager.setCookie(cookieDomain, value)
```

cookieDomain you can find for example using chrome://inspect

Working example:

```
String cookieDomain = ".www.drive2.ru";
String siteUrl = "https://drive2.ru";

webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.web_view);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()); // force open any new url in same webview (whether it is user click or redirect)

CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie(cookieDomain, "cookieName=cookieValue");
webView.loadUrl(siteUrl);
```